# jquery appending all the values

Tags: php, jquery, html

Actually I want to append to div only checked values but it is appending unchecked values also. I used in_array function to check conditions if value is checked means append only checked value not all but it is appending all the values but its checking only value please somebody help me out..

Below is HTML and PHP code:-

```
<div class="flDrop">
    <div class="flDropDiv">
        <?php 
        foreach ($filter_group['filter'] as $filter) { ?>
            <?php 
            if(in_array($filter['filter_id'],$filter_category))
            { ?>
                <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" checked> <?php echo $filter['name'];?> 
            <?php } else {?>
                <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $filter['name'];?> 
            <?php }?>
        <?php }?> 
    </div>   
</div>
```

Jquery code:-

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var filter_len = $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').length
    // alert(filter_len);return false;
    $("#auto_filter_values").empty();
    if(filter_len>1){
      /*$("#auto_filter_values").append('<div class="afr clearall">Clear All filters</div>');*/  
    }
    $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) { 

      $("#auto_filter_values").append('<div class="afr fSbtn" id="fSfilter'+this.value+'" data-val="'+this.value+'">'+$(this).parent().text().replace(/\(([A-Za-z0-9 ]+?)\)/, '')+'<span class="fSc"></span></div>');
    });
    }, 100);
```

Comment: Show us the generated html. Offhand, Id guess that they are all checked in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine with some small changes (an example code):-

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    $.each($("input[name='filter[]']:checked"), function(){ //change here           
        $("#auto_filter_values").append('<div class="afr fSbtn" id="fSfilter'+this.value+'" data-val="'+this.value+'">'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'<span class="fSc"></span></div>'); // changes here
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flDrop">
    <div class="flDropDiv">
        <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="1" data-id ="Black" checked> Black <br>
        <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="2" data-id ="Black">Red<br/>
        <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="3" data-id ="Pink" checked>Pink<br/>
        <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="4" data-id ="Blue">Blue<br/>
    </div>   
</div>

<div id = "auto_filter_values" style ="margin-top:30px;"></div>
```

Note:- you need to add `data-id` attribute with you color name on check-boxes and then you can get easily

Comment: it is appending properly But I want name like blue not like number 82